# Printing `none` in the when in email validation code

Tags: python-3.x

While running the code using `import re` it is printing `None` in the code after output

Here is the code:

```py
import re
email=input()
def checkmail(email):
    if re.match("\A(?P<name>[\w\-_]+)@(?P<domain>[\w\-_]+).(?P<toplevel>[\w]+)\Z",email,re.IGNORECASE):
        print("valid")
    else:
        print("invalid")

print(checkmail(email))
```

How to solve this?

Comment: That is because `checkmail()` does not return anything, so per default, it returns `None`. What would you like it to return?

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the response you are printing.

```
import re
email=input()
def checkmail(email):
    if re.match("\A(?P<name>[\w\-_]+)@(?P<domain>[\w\-_]+).(?P<toplevel>[\w]+)\Z",email,re.IGNORECASE):
        return "valid"
    else:
        return "invalid"

print(checkmail(email))
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.